Proving $g(x) = 1 − \frac{\lVert x−p\rVert}{\delta}$ is continuous
I want to show that given any two points $p, q \in K$ with $p\neq q$ we can choose
a continuous function $g \in C(K)$ so that $g(p)\neq g(q)$, specifically by letting $g(x) = 1 − \frac{\lVert x−p\rVert}{\delta}$ in a ball $B_\delta(p)\cap K$ and $g = 0$ outside of this ball for some number $0 < \delta < \lVert x−p\rVert$. $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I'm stuck on proving this $g$ is continuous. It feels like it should be but I am not sure where to start. For context, I am working up to a proof of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.

@hff1 sure. I guess the only issue is proving continuity at boundary of ball?

It is. Why not take some $y$ at the boundary, a sequence converging to $y$ and then see what happens?

$g_1(x) = 1 - \frac{|x-p|}\delta$ and $g_2(x) = 0$ are both continuous functions on all of $\Bbb R^n$. So $\lim_{x\to q} g_1(x) = g_1(q)$ and $\lim_{x\to q} g_2(x) = g_2(q)$. Show that for all $q$ on the boundary $g_1(q) = g_2(q)$ and use the continuity of $g_1$ and $g_2$ there to prove that $g$ is continuous as well. It can be proven easily from the definition of the limit.
